# checking whether a CheckedListBox is empty

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a small form in which the user writes the name of some item, and then when he clicks "Add" there is a statement that needs to check if there is already the same item in the checkedListBox.

I'm looking for the "if" statment that checked if the list is empty or with some item.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.Items)
    {
        if (itemName.Text == item.ToString())
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("?", "Question", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(itemName.Text);
            }
            else if (result == DialogResult.No)
            {
                //clear the forms
            }
        }
        else
        {
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(itemName.Text);
            timeLeft = 2;
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }
}
        //checkedListBox1.Items.Add(itemName.Text);
        //timeLeft = 2;
        //timer1.Start();
```

Comment: I dont think you can add items to a list while enumerating it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(checkedListBox1.Items.Count > 0) {
     // It contains items
} else {
     // It doesn't
}
```

EDIT:
is for checking if the CheckedListBox is empty or not, then

```
if(checkedListBox1.Items.Contains(theItemToCheck)) {
     // The item is already in the CheckedListBox
}
```

is to check if an item is already in the CheckedListBox.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your `ListBox` contains the item just by using the [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.contains.aspx) method of the collection:

```
if (checkListBox1.Items.Contains(itemName.text))
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you get a look at LINQ?

```
var exists = checkedListBox1.Items.Where(item => item == itemName.Text).Any();
if(exists)
  item exists
else
  item doesn't exists
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code will not work since you may not modify the collection you are iterating.
Trying to do so will result in an `InvalidOperationException` *(Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.)*

You should terminate the loop when you find your match, then get user confirmation and after that modify the list/collection.

So:

1. Try to find a match (and break out of the loop if you are looping over the collection)
2. Get user confirmation
3. Modify the collection

Answer (score 0):

There should be something like checkedListBox1.Items.Count .

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(checkedListBox.Items.Count()>0)
{
    // it means you have items
} 
else
{
    // it means you have empty checkedListBox
}
```